# There is a problem in conversion of text file content into csv format using python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to convert text file content into a `.csv` format by reading each and every line using python csv module and converting that to a list. But i couldn't get the expected output and it stores the first line in a row but second line will be stored in 3rd row  and 5th so on. Since I am new to python i don't know how to skip the line and store it in the right order.

```
def FileConversion():
   try:     
        with open('TextToCSV.txt', 'r') as textFile:
            LineStripped = (eachLine.strip() for eachLine in textFile)
            lines = (eachLine.split(" ") for eachLine in LineStripped if eachLine)            
            with open('finalReport.csv', 'w') as CSVFile:
                writer = csv.writer(CSVFile)
                writer.writerow(('firstName', 'secondName', 'designation', "age"))
                writer.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: Hi @Praveenkumar, I tried your code but it seems to work just fine. Can you show an example of your input and output, just to be sure?

Comment: And also what you expect to get as a result instead of what you got.

Comment: Maybe put your write loop on the outside, instead of the inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try doing something more simple:

```
import pandas as pd
aux = pd.read_csv("TextToCSV.txt", sep=" ")
aux.columns=['firstName', 'secondName', 'designation', "age"]

aux.to_csv("result.csv")
```